# C. ошибка компилятора Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char revOutNum[] = { '0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0',
                    '\0', '\0', '\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0' };

char *func(long long n, short numSys, char *revOutNum)
{
//revOutNum cleaner
    size_t revOutNumSize = strlen(revOutNum) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < revOutNumSize; i++) 
    { 
        revOutNum[i] = '\0'; 
    }
    
    char outNum[] = { '\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0',
                    '\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0' };

    char* sym = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    long long x;
    short c = 0;

    if (n < 0) { x = -n; }
    else { x = n; }

    while (x > 0)
    {
        *(outNum + c) = sym[x % numSys];
        c++;
        x /= numSys;
    }
    if (n < 0) { outNum[c] = '-'; }

//reverse char array
    size_t outNumSize = strlen(outNum) - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= outNumSize; i++) {
        *(revOutNum + i) = outNum[outNumSize - i];
    }

    return revOutNum;
}

int main()
{
    const long d = 0x3D90FE;

    printf("long;%x=%s;35\n", d, func(d, 35, &revOutNum));

    return 0;
}
```

msvs - Visual Studio 2010 (32 bit) выдает ошибку:

```
ss.c(52) : error C2664: 'func' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char (*)[30]' to 'char *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: сначала надо в вопросе показать, как вы передаёте указатель на третий аргумент. `fun(..,.., & "string" ) ;` или `char string[]="string";fun(..,.., & string ) ;` ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe
`func(d, 35, &revOutNum));`

Comment: .. что компилятор и говорит: вы передавали адрес массива, а тип аргумента - указатель. Уберите амперсант. `func(d, 35, revOutNum);` *Надо вопрос задавать полный - чтобы не угадывать ответ.*

Comment: @AlexGlebe да, спасибо
все заработало.
Буду задавать вопросы точнее:)

Comment: прямо сейчас надо исправить вопрос- он зависнет без правильного ответа.

Comment: Цикл обнуления можно заменить за `memset(revOutNum, 0, sizeof(revOutNum));`.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит, что вы передаёте указатель типа `char (*)[30]`, а функция принимает указатель другого типа `char *`.

- тип `char (*)[30]` означает указатель на массив букв размера 30.
- тип `char *` означает указатель на одну букву.

Решается эта проблема, убиранием запроса адреса у переменной `char revOutNum[]`, которая имеет тип массива с размером 30.

```c
func(d, 35, revOutNum)
```

Массив `revOutNum` на самом деле не передаётся в функцию копированием, потому-что язык C автоматически может поставлять адрес первого элемента массива. И фактически работает так :

```c
func(d, 35, & ( revOutNum [ 0 ] ) )
```